# TortoiseGit error: "Remote name must not be empty"

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, git-push, tortoisegit

When I try to push using TortoiseGit to Bitbucket for initial source code, I got error:

> Remote name must not be empty.

I've used TortoiseGit a lot of time and never got any problem with this error even though I never input any *remote name*. It happens only when I try to push. I could commit just fine.

How to solve this?

[image: How the error is shown]

Comment: Yup! I forgot that. But since this is a new project from scratch, I don't even have `origin` for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it myself! I didn't follow the tutorial thoroughly.

Since this is a new repository, I have to add `origin` remote name first. If you use command line, this will do:

```
git remote add origin https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/yourteam/yourrepo.git
```

If you want to do it in TortoiseGit, do this instead:

1. Click manage on the right of dropdown remote name choices
2. Add a remote name `origin` with URL `https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/yourteam/yourrepo.git`
3. Choose it as a remote name then push!

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that no remote repositories are set up or selected right now for pushing/fetching. As all commits are only local in git you only notice this on push/pull/fetch.

Click on the "Manage" button behind the "Remote" combobox in order to set bitbucket up (see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-remote). Afterwards "origin" will show up in the combobox and you can push/pull/fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it via the Interface is to add the origin using the dialog box as follows,

[image]